# Change a picture at a determined time

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way to change a picture on my website if the time is later than 21pm on a certain day. Basically I don't want to have to do it manually since I won't have access to a computer when I need to switch the image. I cannot use PHP as the website I am working on does not support PHP (only ASP).

I guess it could be done in Javascript.

Edit : the picture need to be changed once at 21 and never be changed again not even the day after.

Comment: Do you want it to change the picture 21pm the users local time, or some certain timezone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `Date` object and get the current hour of the day (according to the client), and change the source of the image based on that hour:

```
var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours();
if(hour > 21) {
   document.getElementById("imageID").src = "newImage.png";
}
```

**Update** (based on comments)

If you want the image to change at 21:00 on a certain date, and to remain as that new image after that date (and you really want to use JavaScript for this), then you can create a `Date` object with your specified date/time (e.g. `var d = new Date('June 18, 2011 21:00:00');`) and you can then compare the current date with your specified date when the page loads:

```
var d = new Date('June 18, 2011 21:00:00');
var current = new Date();
if(current > d) {
    document.getElementById("imageID").src = "newImage.png";
}
```

You can see an example of this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/pvRAW/). (Comment out the first line, and comment in the second line to see the difference of future and past dates).

Comment: But will the image stay the same the day after? I really need it to only change once

Comment: Do you mean that you want the image to change at a specific date and time, and to stay as the new image forever after that?

Comment: @Francis - See updated answer for a way to acheive what I think you mean.

Comment: It looks exactly what I am looking for but for some odd reasons it's not working. Image just does not update. Will do some more tests.

Comment: If you've written it correctly, it will work. Here's an updated fiddle, again, uncomment out the other date and the image will change: http://jsfiddle.net/interdream/pvRAW/2/

Comment: How would I trigger this function?

Comment: Put the code in a function (e.g. `function checkDate() { ... }`) and then call the function when the page loads: `<body onload="checkDate();">`

Comment: Worked! thanks I am in the process of learning Javascipt (slowly but surely I only know html, css and how to use jQuery) You saved my friday evening (won't have to manually upload two files)

Comment: No problem! Glad to have been able to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer already posted should work. However, take care, that you have to trigger such function, you can do it on the page onload event, (if you want to check just once when the user load the page); or you can set a timer that every 10 minutes (or the minutes you want), trigger such function. It depends by the nature of your website and the time spent by the user on the page (if it's few minutes at most, it doesen't worth)

Answer (score 0):

use the javascripit date object?

**EDITING Per @Joe's suggestion**

```
    //initialize date object

   function CheckAndChangeImage() {
    var d = new Date();
    var currentHour = d.getHours(); //note 0-23
    var currentDay = d.getDate();
    var currentMonth = d.getMonth();
    var currentYear = d.getYear();  // 2011 == 111

    if (currentHour >= 21 && currentDay >= 17 && currentMonth >= 5 && currentYear >= 111 ) 
     { 
         //do something on late night (21,22,23 hundread hrs)
         document.getElementById('thePicture').src = 'lateNight.png';
      }
  /* commented out, per OP edit 
  else
     { 
        //do something else
       document.getElementById('thePicture').src = 'OtherPicture.png';
      } */
  }

 setInterval(CheckAndChangeImage,60000); //60,000 milliseconds in a minute`
```

this will check that it is equal too or greater than 21hrs on the users machine and the date is after today. the `setInterval(function,ms)` checks every minute so if the user comes to your site at 20:59 it should still change at 21:00. You mentioned the picture needs to be changed once and never again. This solution is very ugly. I would suggest setting up a cron on the local machine to run at 21:00 and update the time site wide. Perhaps PHP could do this, but PHP is not my language of choice. I would likely use python and/or bash for this task. But you could likely accomplish it in Perl. I would suggest an X/HTML parser.

more on the date object

> getDate()   Returns the day of the
>   month (from 1-31)
>       getDay()    Returns the day of the week (from 0-6)
>       getFullYear()   Returns the year (four digits)
>       getHours()  Returns the hour (from 0-23)
>       getMilliseconds()   Returns the milliseconds (from 0-999)
>       getMinutes()    Returns the minutes (from 0-59)
>       getMonth()  Returns the month (from 0-11)
>       getSeconds()    Returns the seconds (from 0-59)
>       getTime()   Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight Jan 1,
>   1970
>       getTimezoneOffset() Returns the time difference between GMT and local
>   time, in minutes
>       getUTCDate()    Returns the day of the month, according to universal time
>   (from 1-31)
>       getUTCDay() Returns the day of the week, according to universal time
>   (from 0-6)
>       getUTCFullYear()    Returns the year, according to universal time
>   (four digits)
>       getUTCHours()   Returns the hour, according to universal time (from
>   0-23)
>       getUTCMilliseconds()    Returns the milliseconds, according to
>   universal time (from 0-999)
>       getUTCMinutes() Returns the minutes, according to universal time
>   (from 0-59)
>       getUTCMonth()   Returns the month, according to universal time (from
>   0-11)
>       getUTCSeconds() Returns the seconds, according to universal time
>   (from 0-59)
>       getYear()   Deprecated. Use the getFullYear() method instead
>       parse() Parses a date string and returns the number of milliseconds
>   since midnight of January 1, 1970
>       setDate()   Sets the day of the month (from 1-31)
>       setFullYear()   Sets the year (four digits)
>       setHours()  Sets the hour (from 0-23)
>       setMilliseconds()   Sets the milliseconds (from 0-999)
>       setMinutes()    Set the minutes (from 0-59)
>       setMonth()  Sets the month (from 0-11)
>       setSeconds()    Sets the seconds (from 0-59)
>       setTime()   Sets a date and time by adding or subtracting a specified
>   number of milliseconds to/from
>   midnight January 1, 1970
>       setUTCDate()    Sets the day of the month, according to universal time
>   (from 1-31)
>       setUTCFullYear()    Sets the year, according to universal time (four
>   digits)
>       setUTCHours()   Sets the hour, according to universal time (from
>   0-23)
>       setUTCMilliseconds()    Sets the milliseconds, according to universal
>   time (from 0-999)
>       setUTCMinutes() Set the minutes, according to universal time (from
>   0-59)
>       setUTCMonth()   Sets the month, according to universal time (from
>   0-11)
>       setUTCSeconds() Set the seconds, according to universal time (from
>   0-59)
>       setYear()   Deprecated. Use the setFullYear() method instead
>       toDateString()  Converts the date portion of a Date object into a
>   readable string
>       toGMTString()   Deprecated. Use the toUTCString() method instead
>       toLocaleDateString()    Returns the date portion of a Date object as a
>   string, using locale conventions
>       toLocaleTimeString()    Returns the time portion of a Date object as a
>   string, using locale conventions
>       toLocaleString()    Converts a Date object to a string, using locale
>   conventions
>       toString()  Converts a Date object to a string
>       toTimeString()  Converts the time portion of a Date object to a
>   string
>       toUTCString()   Converts a Date object to a string, according to
>   universal time
>       UTC()   Returns the number of milliseconds in a date string since
>   midnight of January 1, 1970, according
>   to universal time
>       valueOf()   Returns the primitive value of a Date objecti

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date provides and overview of the date object

so too does w3schools
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Answer (score 0):

You should do this in the backend, this is extra overhead in the client for no real reason, but let's give it a try in JS though!

```
var myDate = new Date();

var curr_hour = myDate.getHours();

var day = myDate.getDate();
var month = myDate.getMonth()+1;
var year = myDate.getFullYear();

if( curr_hour>=21 && ( day==17 && month==5 && year==2011 ) )
    document.getElementById('myPicture').src = 'source.jpg';
```

the picture will be changed after 21,  of 05 / 17 / 2011 (and only for that day)

Comment: Wish I could do it backend but as I said website does not support php and I don't know ASP!

Comment: So that would be the code if I want it to change after 21, of 05 / 17 / 2011 and forever after that

var myDate = new Date();

var curr_hour = myDate.getHours();

var day = myDate.getDate();
var month = myDate.getMonth()+1;
var year = myDate.getFullYear();

if( curr_hour>=21 && ( day>=17 && month>=6 && year>=2011 ) )
    document.getElementById('myPicture').src = 'source.jpg';

Comment: Actually no, because month>=6 and day>=17 means that it will work, only if the month is equals or greater than 6 (june), for example - 05/2012 would not work.  In order to solve this you can either make a bunch of more IF statements, or...   go here    http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm  and grab the timestamp of the day you wish to trigger 05 / 17 / 2011 (21) is  1305666000 (keep in mind that javascript counts in ms, that sites returns seconds, so do a *1000 afterwards - it becomes 1305666000000)  and our if statement becomes  if( (new Date()) >= 1305666000) { /*stuff */ ...